# Error : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, closures

I'm trying to access the values from Bond_Prices, one of the results of the `portfolio_price` function in a for loop outside of the function, but I get the following error:

> "Error in portfolio_price$Bond_Prices : 
>     object of type 'closure' is not subsettable".

Can someone help me with this?

I tried using `portfolio_price$Bond_Prices[1]` as well as `bond_prices`.
The output of Bond_Prices is

```
$Bond_Prices
 [1] 96.15385 86.13218 88.89964 76.28952 75.61329 72.52458 75.99178 68.98708 67.29044 61.39133 61.61987 62.45970 53.03214
```

so I expected `portfolio_price$Bond_Prices[1]` to return 96.15385

```
portfolio_price <- function(){
  bond_prices <- c()

  for(i in 1:length(table_2b$Bond)){
    B0 <- face_value_2/(1+table_2b$Coupon_Rate[i])^i
    bond_prices[i] = B0
    }

  bond_prices_sum <- 0

  for(i in 1:length(table_2b$Bond)){
    bond_prices_sum <- sum(bond_prices_sum,bonds_price[i]*(table_2b$Quantity[i]/table_2b$Quantity))
    }  

  return(list(Bond_Prices = bond_prices, Portfolio_Price = bond_prices_sum))
  }
```

Comment: it looks like you are trying to extract a value from the function `portfolio_price`; R does not work that way. You will need to call the function fist, and its probably good practice to assign it to a variable i.e. `output <- portfolio_price()`. You can the extract the list variables from this i.e. `output$Bond_Prices`

Comment: I assigned portfolio_price() to a variable and it works now. Thank you very much!